# Normalize ImageDistance

Tags: image

I have two images: `im1`,`im2`.
When I compute their distance, using `ImageDistance[im1, im2]` I get a value. However, I would like to normalize this value... So do you know what the maximum image distance can be?

EDIT:

This is so strange:
I have two images...

```
{i1, i2} = {im1, im2}
ImageDistance[i1, i2, DistanceFunction ->NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance]
```

I always get close to 0.5, but the variations when not using the nomalized euclidean distance are much wider. Therefore, is it possible to know the maximum euclidean distance ?

Comment: maybe `DistanceFunction -> NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance`?

Comment: @kglr This always results in 0.5, whatever pictures I use

Answer (score 1):

```
{i1, i2, i3, i4} = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@
   {"Lena", "Mandrill",  "JellyBeans", "JellyBeans2" };
ImageDistance[##, DistanceFunction -> NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance] & @@@ 
 Subsets[{i1, i2, i3, i4}, {2}]
```

> {0.462035, 0.456534, 0.450411, 0.518159, 0.544553, 0.205007}

```
i5 = RandomImage[1, {100, 100}];
i6 = Image[1 - ImageData[i5]];  
ImageDistance[i5, i6, DistanceFunction -> NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance]
```

> 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. See the edit...